# loss of connection randomly... website do not open randomly

Tags: networking, connection, internet-connection

I have windows 10 and Missing packets.. browser does not lood randomly.. Pc is connected to the internet with cable.

```
C:\Windows\system32>ping 8.8.8.8 -n 20
Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=116
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=116
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=116
Request timed out.
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=8ms TTL=116
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=116
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=116
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=116
Request timed out.
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=8ms TTL=116
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=116
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=116
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=116
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=8ms TTL=116
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=116
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=116
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=116


to the router

C:\Windows\system32>ping 192.168.0.1 -n 20

Pinging 192.168.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Do you have any other devices who can connect to the internet?

Comment: Try using MTR or WinMTR or similar to combine traceroute and ping - this will show you where the packet loss is coming in.  My guess is its the connection between you and your ISP, but thats just a guess.  (I comment that having such steady latency with packet loss suggests - but does not prove - its not a congestion issue, although it could be CGNAT related or related to an overburdened router)

Answer (score 1):

It was a problem with the modem.
After its software was refreshed. It started working better.